# Discord bot won't send a message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I started a new project to make a bot for discord, but I always use the same setup every time I create a new discord bot project and update the setup if there is an update in discord.js. **In here**, I was trying to send a **message** when the **user('s)** sends a message.

```
import { Client, IntentsBitField } from "discord.js"
const client = new Client({ 
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages, 
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds
  ] 
});

import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config();

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("astoon bot is READY!");
});

// Detecting if there is a message created.
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content === "ping") {
    message.reply("Pong!");
  };
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code intent to:

```
import { Client, IntentsBitField } from "discord.js"
const client = new Client({ 
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages, 
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent // Add this line.
  ] 
});

import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config();

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("astoon bot is READY!");
});

// Detecting if there is a message created.
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content === "ping") {
    message.reply("Pong!");
  };
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

If you don't do this, you'll get an empty string on `message.content`.
And remember this:
[image: This]